# Split array in 2 parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to split an array of n elements (the array elements number always can be divided in 2), for example I have an array with 20 elements, right now I'm able to split `the first 10 elements and show it` but I don't have any idea of how to split the next 10 elements, here is my code to see more or less what I'm trying to do:

```js
var array = "1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 6, 55, 4, 33, 67, 7, 65, 45, 34, 32, 12, 23";
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    magic();
  });
});

function magic() {
  var split;
  var data = array.split(",");
  var total = data.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < total / 2; i++) {
    array1.push(data[i]);
  }

  $('#a1').text(array1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Magic!</button>

<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a1"></p>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a2"></p>
</div>
```

If you see my code the array 2 elements must be:

> 4, 33, 67, 7, 65, 45, 34, 32, 12, 23

What should I do to do this? In other words, if I have 50 elements I want to fill `array 1` with the first 25 elements and `array 2` with the rest of the elements. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `for (var i = total/2; i < total; i++) { array2.push(data[i]); }`

Comment: @KevinL That works perfect!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
var array = "1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 6, 55, 4, 33, 67, 7, 65, 45, 34, 32, 12, 23";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    magic();
  });
});

function magic() {
  $('#a1').text(array.slice(0, array.length / 2));
  $('#a2').text(array.slice(array.length / 2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Magic!</button>
<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a1"></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS slice:

```
a = array.slice(0,10);
b = array.slice(10,20);
```

You can also use [lodash `chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#chunk) method.

Comment: Generally I would not recommend hard-coding the indexes like that.

Comment: I agree, the focus was on using the slice. The indexing can be done more elegantly in the code, yet, it was not the purpose of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With array.slice() you can give a beginning and end, to answer your hypothetical question:

```
array1 = array.slice(0, 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `slice`

```js
var array = "1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 6, 55, 4, 33, 67, 7, 65, 45, 34, 32, 12, 23";
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    magic();
  });
});

function magic() {
  var split;
  var data = array.split(",");
  var total = data.length;

  array1 = data.slice(0, total / 2);

  array2 = data.slice(total / 2);

  $('#a1').text(array1);
  $('#a2').text(array2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Magic!</button>

<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a1"></p>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <h4>Array 1</h4>
  <p id="a2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice the array:

```js
var myArr = ["1", "5", "4", "3", "2", "6", "7", "8", "6", "55", "4", "33", "67", "7", "65", "45", "34", "32", "12", "23"];
function splitArr(arr2) {
  var arr1 = arr2.splice(0,Math.floor(arr2.length/2))
  return [arr1,arr2];
}
console.log(splitArr(myArr))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.slice()` in javascript

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

```js
var str = "1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 6, 55, 4, 33, 67, 7, 65, 45, 34, 32, 12, 23";
var array = str.split(',');
var len = (array.length) / 2;

var array1 = array.slice(0, len);
var array2 = array.slice(len);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Niona Scholz answer was great, but, with an array of odd lenght don't work well... With this have this problem solved:

```
a.slice(0, Math.ceil(a.length / 2))
a.slice(Math.ceil(a.length / 2))
```